# Is there anyway to see the available client side functions for a ClientProxy?

Tags: signalr

I'm currently debugging a large app that has a few bugs relating to server-side calls over client-side endpoints not resulting in client-side invocations. From a debugging standpoint I'm a bit lost at sea. It would help me to see the list of available client-side functions, but that may not be available. From a tracelog standpoint I see no entries that shine any light as to there being anything wrong with the function call (`system.diagnostics` entry below).

Any thoughts as to unit tests or debugging strategies?

```
<switches>
  <add name="SignalRSwitch" value="Verbose" />
</switches>
<!-- Specifies the trace writer for output -->
<sharedListeners>
  <!-- Listener for transport events -->
  <add name="SignalR-Transports" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="transports.log.txt" />
  <!-- Listener for scaleout provider events -->
  <add name="SignalR-Bus" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="bus.log.txt" />
  <!-- Listener for hub discovery events -->
  <add name="SignalR-Init" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="init.log.txt" />
</sharedListeners>
<trace autoflush="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, at least **on the server**,  no. The code defined on the client to handle server-to-client calls is just a bunch of *event handlers* totally unknown to the server. You could in theory have several client-side pieces of code each one with different handlers, without any way for the server to know about all of them. That would be totally legit and makes it easier to understand why it is not possible to know what you ask for.

Behind the scenes SignalR just sends *messages* for each server-to-client call, where each message has some *fields*, one of them containing the client side *name* of the *event* to trigger. So, the server just sends strings *and forgets about them*, the client receives them and dynamically checks if any handler exist for that name.

Is your goal to avoid calling stuff like `Clients.All.foo("bar")` if `foo` does not exist on the client? And maybe you have several places in your code where this could potentially happen, so it becomes hard to keep dynamic calls under control when stuff is reorganized/refactored? If yes, then one suggestion could be to define a new C# type, and centralize each of the dynamic calls on the server inside corresponding methods of that type. By using an instance of that type (it could also be static), your hubs or calls through `IHubContext` could not possibly go wrong, and you centralize the dynamic calls in one place. This of course does not solve the problem completely, but helps to keep it under control because the dynamic calls are just in one place and it becomes easier to keep them aligned with client side code.

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries that wrap SignalR and make it more static typed. I'm the author of one such library called [SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy](https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy)

It's a pub/sub wrapper and the messages are C# classes that are proxied to the clients using a dynamic script (Much like the hub proxy)